# Python: Add atribute to object named after an existing string

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I want to be able to add an attribute to an existing object based on a particular string. So, for example, if `mystring = 'bar'` and the object is called `foo`, then what I would like to be able to assign `foo.mystring = False` such that `foo.bar = False`. So given:

```
class Fubar():
    def __init__(self):
        self = self
        self.bar = True


foo = Fubar() 
mystring = 'bar'
```

What is the actual equivalent of the pseudocode `foo.mystring = False` such that:

```
print(foo.bar)
False
```

Keep in mind that I do not necessarily know what `mystring` contains, only that it references an attribute that I would like to assign to the existing object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setattr(foo, mystring, False)   # this is just here to let me submit
```